# InfluxDB mixing agregation function with non-aggregat fields/values

Tags: influxdb, non-relational-database

I have a following issue:
I need to calculate difference between consecutive points where some arbitrary `ID` is equal. The following:

`SELECT difference(value_field) FROM mesurementName WHERE "IdField" = '10'`

Works, returns difference between each consecutive point with `IdField` BUT  `IdField` is lost (only `time` is propagated to query result). In my case `time` is not unique (i.e. measurement may contain many points with same `timestamp`, but different `IdField`). So I tried:

`SELECT difference(value_field), IdField  FROM mesurementName WHERE "IdField" = '10'`

which yields:
`error parsing query: mixing aggregate and non-aggregate queries is not supported!!`

My next attempt was using sub-query:

```
SELECT IdField, diff
FROM (
    SELECT 
        difference(flow_val) as diff
    FROM 
        mesurementA
    WHERE  "IdField" = '10' 
)
```

Which resulted in always `null` value in `IdField`.

I'd like to ask you for help or suggestion how to solve issue. By the way, we are using InfluxDB 1.3, which is not supporting `JOIN` anymore

Answer (score 3):

If anyone would stuck as I was, then solution is following:

```
SELECT difference(value_field) FROM mesurementName GROUP BY "IdField"
```

Above somehow implicitly add "IdField" to result series and is propagated to resulting measurements with `INTO` clause